# TypeError: takes exactly 1 argument (0 given) using Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, typeerror

I'm writing a Tkinter code using checkboxes list.

When I try execute the code, the GUI works fine until I clicked on the "Trigger" button.

This is my code:

```
from Tkinter import*

root = Tk()
root.wm_title("Triggering System")
root.config(background = "#2471A3")

def terminate():
    global root
    root.destroy()


def var_states(var1):
    file_name = r'D:\log.txt'
    with open(file_name, 'wb') as x_file:
        x_file.write('{} TotalAmount'.format(var1()))


leftFrame = Frame(root, width=800, height=600)
leftFrame.grid(row=0 , column=0, padx=10, pady=4)
leftFrame.config(background = "#D6EAF8")
leftFrame.pack(fill=X)

firstLabel = Label(leftFrame, text="Triggering System")
firstLabel.grid(row=1, column=0, padx=10, pady=2)
firstLabel.config(background = "#2471A3")
firstLabel.config(font=("Impact", 22))
firstLabel.pack(fill=X)

secondLabel = Label(leftFrame, text="Downtime Cause:",anchor = "w")
secondLabel.grid(row=2, column=0, padx=10, pady=2)
secondLabel.config(background = "#D6EAF8")
secondLabel.config(font=("Arial Narrow", 18))
secondLabel.pack(fill=X)

var1 = IntVar()
var1 = Checkbutton(leftFrame, text="Material Shortages",variable=var1,anchor = "w")
var1.grid(row=3, column=0, padx=10, pady=2)
var1.config(background = "#F7DC6F")
var1.config(font=("Tahoma", 12))
var1.pack(fill=X)

var2 = IntVar()
var2 = Checkbutton(leftFrame, text="Wrong Component",variable=var2,anchor = "w")
var2.grid(row=4, column=0, padx=10, pady=2)
var2.config(background = "#F7DC6F")
var2.pack(fill=X)
var2.config(font=("Tahoma", 12))

SendResult = Button(leftFrame, text = "Trigger", command=var_states)
SendResult.grid(row=5, column=1, padx=2, pady=2)
SendResult.config(font=("Tahoma", 12))
SendResult.pack(fill=X)


mainloop()
```

However, upon clicking the "Triger" button , I am getting this kind of error:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\Python27\lib\lib-tk\Tkinter.py", line 1542, in __call__
        return self.func(*args)
    TypeError: var_states() takes exactly 1 argument (0 given)
```

Comment: According to your traceback you ran `C:\Python27\lib\lib-tk\Tkinter.py` directly, which would be odd.

Comment: im sorry since im new to Python , if this is odd how should I ran it

Comment: How did you run it actually?

Comment: i press on F5, the GUI is able to be executed , however error occured when I clicked on the Trigger button , var1 and var2 should return value

Comment: You didn't pass var1 to var_states command.

Answer (score 0):

You defined your method to take one argument,

```
def var_states(var1):
```

but you are calling it without any.

```
SendResult = Button(..., command=var_states)
```

You can use `lambda` here to pass an argument to your method.

```
SendResult = Button(...,  command= lambda: var_states(argumentToSend))
```

Comment: @H.Woo You need to change `argumentToSend` to whatever you want var1 be in your method.

Comment: i tried to edit using the lambda method and it's elimate the error, however as I tried to pass the checkbox result to the file "log" this error occured

  File "C:\Python27\lib\lib-tk\Tkinter.py", line 1542, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "D:\Python Lesson\Checkbox\Checkbox1.py", line 49, in <lambda>
    SendResult = Button(leftFrame, text = "Trigger", command=lambda:var_states(var1))
  File "D:\Python Lesson\Checkbox\Checkbox1.py", line 15, in var_states
    x_file.write(var1.get())
AttributeError: Checkbutton instance has no attribute 'get'

Comment: The code was written as per this

def var_states(var1):
    file_name = r'D:\log.txt'
    with open(file_name, 'wb') as x_file:
        x_file.write(var1.get())

Comment: Name of checkbutton variable and argument used in method are same. Change one. Also, when using checkbutton you need one of StringVar/IntVar for variable option. Please read more about checkbuttons.